# Android Debug Bridge is unable to connect to Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, adb

I try to connect my mobile phone via adb connect to my pc. but there is always a error message:

```
C:> adb connect ip
unable to connect to ip:5555
```

I am using Windows 7 and a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini (GT-I9195) with android 4.2.2. 
If i connect vie USB it works. Also it works with an Asus Tablet with Android 4.0.3
I've installed the latest version of the SDK

Comment: Is debugging enabled on the device? Enabling debugging on 4.2.2 requires a special procedure.

Comment: debugging is enabled. The reason was that the adb wasn't running on port 5555. adb tcpip 5555 with the device connected via USB solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Make shure that your device is connected via USB when lauching the command. Then adb connect should work.